# Exception when upload blob to Storage Account

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I converted this code from c# to Powershell. It works with c# code but there is an exception with Powershell. They use the same NuGet package. Could someone help me? Thank you very much !

```
var cred = new AzureSasCredential(@"sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=nnJ48zy4yPtagsfgsdfgsdgfyYzJxChMrVNLM%3D&st=2021-06-02T06:52:33Z&se=2021-06-03T06:52:33Z&sp=w");
var client = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri("https://fasdfasfdasf.blob.core.windows.net/deploymentpackages"), cred);

BlobClient blob = client.GetBlobClient("a.jpg");
blob.Upload("D:\\a.jpg");
```

Powershell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\dkng\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\packages\Azure.Core.1.14.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\dkng\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\packages\Azure.Storage.Blobs.12.8.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\dkng\.nuget\packages\azure.storage.common\12.7.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Azure.Storage.Common.dll")

$sasCredential = New-Object Azure.AzureSasCredential -ArgumentList "sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&sig=nnJ48zy4yP9GrSbTiOT695h4vmZph4yYzJxChMrVNLM%3D&st=2021-06-02T06:52:33Z&se=2021-06-03T06:52:33Z&sp=w"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList "https://fasdfasfdasf.blob.core.windows.net/deploymentpackages"

$client = New-Object -TypeName Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient([System.Uri]$uri, [Azure.AzureSasCredential]$sasCredential)
$blob = $client.GetBlobClient("a.jpg");
try
{
    $blob.Upload("D:\\a.jpg");
}
catch [Exception]
{
    echo $_.Exception|format-list -force
}
```

There error is:

```
InnerExceptions : {Azure.RequestFailedException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
                     
HelpLink        : 
Source          : Azure.Core
HResult         : -2146233088
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the input parameters? Please obfuscate `account name` and `sig` portion of your SAS token.

Comment: Why do you not use Azure PowerShell module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-6.0.0?

Comment: I did, but other people have to install Az.Storage module in their local machine. Sometimes they get issues with the module version. I build a module and publish it to Powershell gallery. I don't want it depends on Az.Storage module anymore, so other people do not have to install that module in their local machine

Comment: COuld you please use fiddler to catch request?